# Best place to put MouseListener for resizing windows

Tags: java, swing, resize, mouseevent

I'm working on an undecorated frame and I'm currently working on resizing and moving the `JFrame`. I've completed both of them, but unfortunately it is very buggy due to the fact that I've placed both `MouseListener`s for moving and dragging on the same component.

Moving windows involves clicking anywhere inside the window, except of course near its borders where I want to handle all the resizing.

Where should I place my `MouseListener` (resizing)?

I've thought about making a border but I wasn't sure where. Any suggestions?

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: @JoshM: I'll provide some code once I get home. Sorry about that.

Comment: I already gave you example code for this. Not only that I also gave you code for moving components as well. You need to add the listeners to the same component, but yes the resizing listener only looks at event near the border and the moving listener looks at event inside the border.

Comment: @camickr: Thank you for all those help. I actually used that a couple of months ago however it didn't work properly with multiple monitors. I'm trying to do my own implementation now for learning purposes. My own implementation isn't very "smooth," especially if the mouse is moved very fast. It actually moves the window (while resizing) if I drag it fast enough. So my alternative was to put the two listeners on different components to prevent that, thus comes this question.